# Arrange layout of a struct to automatically conform to GLSL std140

Tags: c#, struct, glsl, memory-alignment

For a GPU to consume data from CPU memory, the layout assumed by the GPU must match the layout of how the data is stored in CPU memory. This assumption is encoded by the [std140 rules](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/opengl-programming-guide/9780132748445/app09lev1sec2.html).

I'd like the C# compiler to arrange the layout of my struct automatically according to std140. Some of these rules are:

- The alignment of `float` is 4 (`= sizeof(float)`).
- The alignment of a 2-element vector of floats `vec2` is 8 (`= 2 * sizeof(float)`).
- The alignment of a 4-element vector of floats `vec4` is 16 (`= 4 * sizeof(float)`).

It is not relevant for this question to know all the rules, so let us assume that the above three cover all the rules.

I would like to be able to write something like:

```
[Std140Layout]
public struct Data 
{
    public float x;
    public vec2 y;
    public float z;
    public vec4 w;
}
```

And have it automatically generate the following code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Data 
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] 
    public float x;
    
    [FieldOffset(8)] 
    public vec2 y;

    [FieldOffset(16)] 
    public float z;
    
    [FieldOffset(32)] 
    public vec4 w;
}
```

Is this possible to achieve by e.g. reflection, and if so, how?

Comment: Can you not just do `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]` and set `vec3` to `Pack = 8`

Comment: @Charlieface `vec2` could be `System.Numerics.Vector2`, for example. Not sure what you mean by setting Pack for `vec2`, but if it involves adding an attribute to class declaration, then I cannot do it for `System.Numerics.Vector2`.

Comment: No but then whatever you do there is no way to do that from the outer struct. `FieldOffset` wouldn't help there either, as it only affects where the `Vector3` as a whole is positioned. You would need your own `vec3` struct, or hope that the default packing on your architecture is correct. But maybe you don't need to bother: I think the requirement is just that it needs to be the right size, so you could use a `Vector4` there. And your current struct doesn't use that problematic `vec3` anyway.